# How to remove duplicate string in string in python

Tags: python

I want to keep a single sentence in string with many the same sentences.
**Input**:

```
str1 = 'I want to do this to help her to get the job done I want to do this to help her to get the job done'
```

**Expected output**:

```
str2 = 'I want to do this to help her to get the job done'
```

Not missing some "to". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```py
out = []
for word in str1.split():
    if word not in out:
        out.append(word)

res = " ".join(out)
```

Comment: this code have a problem. example

Comment: this code have a problem. example input ```str1 = ' I want to do this to help her to get the job done' but output just  I want to do this to help her to get the job done``` and output ```str2='I want to do this help her get the job done'``` it missing some "to"

Comment: If you want to support this behaviour then you would need to define your problem better. What do you consider a sentence? (you have to give a rigorous algorithmic answer that does not rely on semantics)